# Get Next Element in the std::list using iterator

Tags: c++, stl

I am trying to get difference between consecutive elements in a std::list. I attempted the following solution but as [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2699680/stdlist-iterator-get-next-element) thread says, I need to make a copy of iterator and increment it. Not sure what it mean since adding number to iterators also result in error. what am I missing here. I am using a previous version of C++ but not C++ 11

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <list>
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    std::list<int> myList;
    //for (int i = 10;i < 15;i++)
    myList.push_back(12);
    myList.push_back(15);
    myList.push_back(18);
    myList.push_back(19);
    myList.push_back(25);

    for (std::list<int>::const_iterator itr = myList.begin();itr != myList.end();++itr)
    {
        int x = *itr;
        int y = *(itr + 1);
        int diff = std::abs(x - y);
        cout << diff << "\n";
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Adding to an iterator requires a [random access iterator](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/concept/RandomAccessIterator). `std::list` does not provide this kind of iterator.  Instead it is only a [Bidirectional Iterator](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/concept/BidirectionalIterator). Also watch out for the last element.

Answer (score 3):

How about using [`adjacent_difference`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/adjacent_difference) ?

```
std::adjacent_difference(myList.begin(), myList.end(), tempList );
```

[`See Here`](http://rextester.com/GQHJD40282)

---

If you're interested in implementation look how its implemented in `Possible Implementation` section in attached link. All you have to do is replace with list iterator and for output just display on screen, or store it.

Comment: This will have an extra first element.Right?

Comment: @GauravSehgal Yeah see the algorithm as well, you can always print starting second index after _some check_

Answer (score 1):

You can use `std::advance()` to get to the next iterator

```
int x = *itr;
std::list<int>::const_iterator itr2 = itr;
std::advance(itr2,1);
if(itr2==myList.end())
    break;
int y = *(itr2);
int diff = std::abs(x - y);
cout << diff << "\n";
```

EDIT: If `c++ 11` available, see [std::next](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/iterator/next)

Comment: Ohh sorry I am using a previous version of C++ but not C++11

Comment: @Programmerzzz Best to add that to the question so everyone can see it. Otherwise you'll get more answers like this one.

Answer (score 1):

Use increment operator to move iterator.

```
auto x = itr;
auto y = itr;
if(++y!=myList.end())
{
    int diff = std::abs(*x - *y);
    cout << diff << "\n";
}
```

Comment: I think this gives the difference between the first element and rest of the elements in the list but not between consecutive elements.

Comment: @Programmerzzz This answer is pulling a fast one on you. Mayur has repurposed and retyped `x` and `y`. This works, but needs some explanation.

Answer (score 1):

```
#include <list>
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
    std::list<int> myList;
    //for (int i = 10;i < 15;i++)
    myList.push_back(12);
    myList.push_back(15);
    myList.push_back(18);
    myList.push_back(19);
    myList.push_back(25);
    for (std::list<int>::const_iterator itr = myList.begin();
                              itr != std::prev(myList.end());
                                                      ++itr)
    {
        std::list<int>::const_iterator nextIt = std::next(itr);
        int diff = *itr - *nextIt;
        std::cout << diff << "\n";
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Use `std::next(itr)` to get next iterator 
and use `std::prev(myList.end())` in for loop to get previous of last element in list.

Also you can change your for loop and use `std::advance()` to get next iterator without using `std::next` and `std::prev`

```
std::list<int>::const_iterator itr = myList.begin();
while (true)
{
    int prevValue= *itr;
    std::advance(itr, 1);
    if (itr == myList.end())
    {
        break;
    }
    int diff = prevValue - *itr;
    std::cout << diff << "\n";

}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can copy the iterator and run two, but I think it's easier to get the first value outside of the loop and then use the loop to iterate through the second value, resetting the first value with the second before proceeding to the next.

Something like this:

```
#include <list>
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
    std::list<int> myList;
    myList.push_back(12);
    myList.push_back(15);
    myList.push_back(18);
    myList.push_back(19);
    myList.push_back(25);
    std::list<int>::const_iterator itr = myList.begin();
    if(itr != myList.end()) // is a first value
    {
        int last = *itr; // cache it
        for (itr++; itr != myList.end(); itr++) // get next value
        { 
            int current = *itr; //cache it
            int diff = std::abs(last - current);
            std::cout << diff << "\n";
            last = current; // update last value
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Another way would be to simply keep track of the previous list element value, not the iterator, and to subtract that previous value from the element the iterator is currently pointing to; like so:

```
#include <list>
#include <cmath> // need cmath for std::abs
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
  std::list<int> myList;
  //for (int i = 10;i < 15;i++)
  myList.push_back(12);
  myList.push_back(15);
  myList.push_back(18);
  myList.push_back(19);
  myList.push_back(25);
  int PreviousElement = 0;
  bool Start = false;
  for (std::list<int>::const_iterator itr = myList.begin(); itr != myList.end(); ++itr)
  {
    if (Start)
    {
      int diff = std::abs(*itr - PreviousElement);
      cout << diff << "\n";
    }
    else
    {
      Start = true;
    }
    PreviousElement = *itr;
  }

  return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you need two iterator to solve this question
Here's my code

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <list>

#include <iterator>
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    std::list<int> myList;
    //for (int i = 10;i < 15;i++)
    myList.push_back(12);
    myList.push_back(15);
    myList.push_back(18);
    myList.push_back(19);
    myList.push_back(25);
    int x = 0;
    int y = 0;
    std::list<int>::iterator itr;
    std::list<int>::iterator it_next;

    for (itr = myList.begin(), it_next = ++myList.begin();it_next != myList.end();itr++, it_next++)
    {

        x = *itr;
        y = *it_next;
        int diff = abs(x - y);
        cout << diff << "\n";
    }

    system("PAUSE");
    return 0;
}
```

I build it in VC++2005 but it should work fine in C++
Hope this will help you :)

Comment: Result of these code should look like [this](https://imgur.com/nAa54Eu)